# Redux presentation component UI state management

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have a container and presentation components as described below

```
Components
  |-Containers
    |- App.tsx
    |- ServiceContainer.tsx
  |-Presentation
    |-ServiceList.tsx
    |-ServiceListItem.tsx
```

Question: I have read that presentation containers should not have any state and just render data from the props and also the props passed cannot be mapped the local state -- which is great but I need a hover state on **ServiceListItem**. When I hover, I need to show the description of the service. how do I do this without creating a local state on the presentation component? Do I have to create an action and reducers for the presentation component?

Here are my codes. I have setup store,reducers and actions.

**App.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import ServicesContainer from "./containers/ServicesContainer";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { IStateProps, IDispatchProps, ServiceListProps } from "../types/services/serviceModel";
import ServiceActionCreators from "../actions/serviceRecordActions";


class App extends React.Component<ServiceListProps>{

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <ServicesContainer {...this.props}/>
    )
  }
}


function mapStateToProps(state:any): IStateProps{
  return {services: state.serviceRecords}
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch:any): IDispatchProps{

  const dispatchProps : any = {
      fetchServiceRecords : ServiceActionCreators.fetchServiceRecords,
      addServiceRecord: ServiceActionCreators.addServiceRecord,
      removeServiceRecord: ServiceActionCreators.removeServiceRecord
  }

  return bindActionCreators(dispatchProps, dispatch);

}
```

**ServiceContainer.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import ServiceList from "../presentations/ServiceList";
import { ServiceListProps } from "../../types/services/serviceModel";


const ServicesContainer = (props: ServiceListProps) => {
    return (
        <ServiceList {...this.props}/>
    );
}

export default ServicesContainer;
```

**ServiceList.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { ServiceListProps} from "../../types/services/serviceModel";
import ServiceListItem from "../presentations/ServiceListItem";

// Stateless Component
class ServiceList extends React.Component<ServiceListProps> {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <ul>
                {
                    this.props.services.map((s) => (
                        <ServiceListItem 
                            key={s.service.Id}
                            service={s.service}
                        />
                    ))
                }
            </ul>
        )
    }
}


export default ServiceList;
```

**ServiceListItem.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import {ServiceListItemModel} from "../../types/services/serviceModel";

// Stateless Component

const ServiceListItem = (props:ServiceListItemModel) => {
    return(
        <li>

            {props.service.Name} 

            <a href="#" >Remove</a>
            // On Hover, I want to show this <p> tag
            <p > - {props.service.Description}</p> 

        </li>
    )
}

export default ServiceListItem;
```

**UPDATE (with solution)**
This works as intended. No props to state map and just displays data from props

```
class ServiceListItem extends React.Component<ServiceListItemProps, any> {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        // only UI state changes
        this.state = {showDescription: false}
    }

    toggleDescription(){
        this.setState(prevState => ({showDescription: !prevState.showDescription}))
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <li 
                onMouseOver={() => this.toggleDescription()} 
                onMouseLeave={() => this.toggleDescription()}
                >

                {this.props.service.Name} 

                <a href="#" >Remove</a>

                {this.state.showDescription &&
                    <p > - {this.props.service.Description}</p> 
                }

            </li>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want that part of your application to be handled by redux, then you will need actions change the store state and pass a isHovering or something like that to the component, and reducers that handle those actions. I personally would use a component and local state to handle hover though. Not everything has to be in redux. I only put things in redux that I would need to hydrate a view, or support further action within that view. Hovering is not such a case.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that presentational components should not have state, but the state here refers purely to data driven state that is fetched from cloud or some IO. Such state needs to be handled in container components.

As quoted by Dan Abramov in his [article](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) :

> - Presentational components are concerned with how things look.
> - Rarely have their own state (when they do, it’s UI state rather than data).

In the ServiceListItem component which is presentational, its perfectly fine to have a local state which will control the hover behaviour as it is a UI construct which is still agnostic of the data driven state.

Comment: @nuru-salihu 
Your solution results in multiple alerts because one single hover state defined in the ServiceList  container will be passed as prop to all instances of ServiceListItem, whereas ideally each instance should have its own separate hover state inside its implementation.

Comment: yup! that's what happened when I tried @nuru-salihu's solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use on hover event and set the state back to the container state like below

**ServiceList.tsx**

```
// Stateless Component
class ServiceList extends React.Component<ServiceListProps> {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {hover: false};
    }

   //note here
   onHover(status: boolean) {
     this.setState({hover: status});
   }


    render(){
        return (
            <ul>
                {
                    this.props.services.map((s) => (
                        <ServiceListItem 
                            key={s.service.Id}
                            service={s.service}
                            hover={this.state.hover}
                            onHandleHoverEvent={this.onHover}
                        />
                    ))
                }
            </ul>
        )
    }
}


export default ServiceList;
```

And then

```
// Stateless Component

const ServiceListItem = (props:ServiceListItemModel) => {
    return(
        <li onMouseOver={() => this.props.onHandleHoverEvent(true)} onMouseOut={() => this.props.onHandleHoverEvent(false)}>

            {props.service.Name} 

            <a href="#" >Remove</a>
            { props.hover &&
               <p> - {props.service.Description}</p>
             }

        </li>
    )
}

export default ServiceListItem;
```

Comment: This shows all the description of my list item if I hover on any one of the item. I only want to show the description of the hovered item.

Comment: @SabinMaharjan it should actually shows the hovered li only if i am not mistaken. Perhaps you are doing it wrong.